# How to add multiple divs in mouseover (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have 7 declared divs with different class attributes using jquery. I would like to use the 7 divs in mouseover. How would I do this?

My 7 divs are divOne, divTwo ... until divSeven.

I have this sample mouseover code but only one div is used.

```
                    nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 30)
                    .style("stroke","white")
                    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                        divOne.transition()
                          .duration(200)
                          .style("opacity", .9);
                        divOne.html(
                           "Name" + "<br />" + "Address"
                         ) 
                          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                        })
                      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                        divOne.transition()
                          .duration(500)
                          .style("opacity", 0);
                        });
```

How to add the other divs during mouseover? Any help. Thanks

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the HTML and the JS and add it to your post please?

Comment: what you mean by *add multiple divs*, you want to bind multiple divs on mouseover or on to append multiple divs on mouseover.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246650/how-to-create-a-jquery-mouseover-for-multiple-divs-by-id

Comment: @Khaleel He is looking for some code which will allow him to add all the seven divs in that block of code without having him to write code for seven separate divs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something like this.

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
         .attr("r", 30)
         .style("stroke", "white")
         .on("mouseover", function(d) {
             onMouseOver();
         })
         .on("mouseout", function(d) {
             onMouseOut();
         });

 var divElements = $('.classofdiv1', '.classofdiv2'......); //add all the div's class

 function onMouseOver() {
     $(divElements).each(function(index) {
         $(this).transition()
             .duration(200)
             .style("opacity", .9);
         $(this).html(
                 "Name" + "<br />" + "Address"
             )
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

     });
 }

 function onMouseOut() {
     $(divElements).each(function(index) {
         $(this).transition()
             .duration(500)
             .style("opacity", 0);

     });
 }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello. I would like to ask about the divElements, is it the name of my divs or its class attributes?

Comment: it is class attributes. u can also use `document.getElementsByClassName('nameOfClassHere');` if same class applies to all divs

Comment: ok thanks. I'd prefer to use your solution above coz my divs have different classes.

Comment: Ok. is it working now.? Please vote up and accept answer if it works . Or post comments if u need any further help on this

Comment: wat is the error u r getting in console. did u try replace `$(this)` with `index`

Comment: ohh gosh! please bear with my comment above, it's so complicated. Well, that was supposed to be displayed during the mouseover. On the other hands, no errors are displayed. I haven't tried to use the index.

Comment: for the format u commented, my solution ll work, try placing breakpoints and debug, see if element is selected correctly

Comment: What solution II are you referring to? Is it the document.getElementsByClassName('nameOfClassHere')?